# What database to use if I need to deploy an app with one small table?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c#-4.0

I need to create a very simple app that has one table that will need to store records over time. What is the best way to do this with vs 2010 if i do not want to install a database engine on the end users machine.

I would like to just package up the database file with the exe when deploying. There will only be one user accesses the table but i do not want to have to install sql express on the end users computer.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) - if it is just one table and not very much data you might consider just using an XML file as well though.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- (typed) DataSet using Write() and Load() to save the data to an XML
  file (very convenient with Visual Studio)
- SQLite
- Object serialization

Answer (score 2):

Try either SQL Server Compact or in another scenario which I dont like MS Access.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access

Answer (score 2):

Some options for embedded relational database systems:

- [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)
- [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)

For a more complete overview see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Answer (score 1):

if you want to save data very simple,you may Serialize data to XML file, or if you want to save as smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Add Dataset, when you start program load it to memory, when you close program you may save it as xml file.